# How to prevent blur from adding input in v-combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In Vuetify.js, when using `<v-combobox>` when I click away, the value I had typed is added to the model.

How can I prevent this?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVQBWz?&editable=true&editors=101

What's strange is that the JSFiddle in the example site works, but if I copy the HTML/JS exactly into my app I experience this.

Comment: I copied your code in a simple html file and it works as the same as your codepen snippet, could you be more clear about the behavior you want to prevent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reset the input value on blur

`<v-combobox @blur="search = ''"`